# Datatype and filter for a SDE connection parameter in a Python toolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-toolbox, parameters

I have a tool in a Python toolbox. As a parameter, I want to let the user select an existing (or possibly create a new) SDE connection. What value for `datatype` should I use for this?

I have tried `DERemoteDatabaseFolder`, definied by the [documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameter-data-types-in-a-python-toolbox.htm) as:

> The database connection folder in ArcCatalog.

However, it only lets me select files of mysterious "Basic Types" and does not show me any SDE files. I also tried `DEFile`, setting `param.filter.list = ['sde']`. But that options required the user to find the SDE files on her own, which is not so easy if they are located somewhere in the `AppData\Roaming` folder.

Is there any better alternative?

Comment: Try 'workspace'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@KHibma is right. Use `DEWorkspace`

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Input Sde Connection",
        name="in_conn_file",
        datatype="DEWorkspace",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
```

To  limit the choices:

```
param0.filter.type = "Workspace"
param0.filter.list = ["Remote Database"]
```

Comment: What if that doesn't work with your script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment on @Farid Cheraghi's [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/170566/67651) which mostly worked for me with one change:
After creating param0, if I use

```
param0.filter.type = "Workspace"
```

The tool shows with a red x in the Catalog pane of ArcMap. Right clicking and selecting the "Why..." menu option brings up a Python Errors window with this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<my filename.py>", line 64, in getParameterInfo
    param0.filter.list = "Workspace"
  File "d:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 89, in _set
    return setattr(self._arc_object, attr_name, cval(val))
ValueError: FilterObject: Input value must be a list
```

But if I just take that line out and only use

```
param0.filter.list = ["Remote Database"]
```

I am able to see .sde files in the parameter file picker window. This is with ArcMap 10.6.1 so something may have changed since version 10.3.